# Accessing or referring to UIImageView from the viewController

Tags: ios, swift

Total iOS/Swift newb here.  I have a View (or UIImageView, don't think it matters) on my storyBoard and I need to refer to it in my viewController code.  How do I do that?

Why?  I'm trying to show the camera preview in a 'view' that is not full screen.

I'm using example code for the camera, which includes this code

```
func beginSession() {
var err : NSError? = nil
captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))

if err != nil {
    println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
}

previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame
captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

that seems to be saying, put the previewLayer in the (main) 'view' on my storyboard.

So I figured, and researched, that I could add a sub View (or a UIImageView) to my storyboard and make it the size I want, and then add previewLayer to it.

Eg. from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768210/custom-camera-view-swift-ios-8-iphone-xcode-6-1) on SO

> ... and then change the part at the bottom that says,
>
> "previewLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame"
>
> to your 200by200 View.layer.frame

Ok, so how do I get my 200x200 view, so I can access its frame (not even sure what layer and frame are at this point)?

I tried control drag the view, or UIImageView to the viewController from the storyboard, but it didn't work (did nothing).

Comment: To access any object from the Storyboard in your ViewController, you need to add an Outlet connection. Open the StoryBoard, open Assistant Editor (View / Assistant Editor), and CONTROL-DRAG a line from the view to the ViewController code, creating a new Outlet connection.

Comment: You said you have tried to control drag from the Storyboard to the ViewController, but what View you tried to connect? You should crieate a View (let's say an UIImageView), to hold your image, and then show the Assistant Editor (this is important) and then Control-drag to it. This action should create a new Class variable, marked as @IBOutlet. Did you try this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Paste this line in your view controller's class:

   @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
2. Open storyboard and select your view controller
3. Open a connections inspector at the right side of Xcode window.
4. Connect imageView outlet's circle with your image view.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks!  Good way too.

Answer (score 3):

I think my little tutorial and source code will help you!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And fill the code in ViewController.swift
https://gist.github.com/MihaelIsaev/273e4e8ddaaf062d2155

Full source code here
https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/SwiftCameraView

Comment: Sweet!  Didn't realise I was supposed to literally drag it into the code, thought it was supposed to go to that yellow 'View Controller' icon... Thanks!  Will award bounty in 18 hrs when I am allowed.

Comment: Sweet! Will wait for bounty award ^_^